# What is the meaning of the following sentence. I didn't understand the way sentence is constructed

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

**“Psychotherapy would not only reflect a nihilistic philosophy but also, even though unwillingly and unwittingly, transmit to the patient what is actually a caricature rather than a true picture of man.”**

Excerpt From: Viktor E. Frankl. “Man's Search for Meaning.” Apple Books.

Comment: It's not possible to parse the sentence without more context. It could either mean *transmit to the patient **[something that]** is actually a caricature* or it could mean *transmit to the patient **[who]** is actually a caricature*. I suspect it's the former, but I couldn't swear to that without reading earlier passages.

Comment: It's obviously a *translation*, so perhaps  it would be better to consider the original German text. Personally I think there's something "not quite right" about asking ELL to analyse the ***semantic*** content of translated material like this.

Comment: Read it like this first: “Psychotherapy would not only reflect a nihilistic philosophy but also transmit to the patient what is actually a caricature rather than a true picture of man.” Then add the adverbs back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preceding sentences explain the meaning of the sentence in question.

> As for psychotherapy, however, it will never be able to cope with this state of affairs on a mass scale if it does not keep itself free from the impact and influence of the contemporary trends of a nihilistic philosophy; otherwise it represents a symptom of the mass neurosis rather than its possible cure. *Psychotherapy would not only reflect a nihilistic philosophy but also, even though unwillingly and unwittingly, transmit to the patient what is actually a caricature rather than a true picture of man.*

The sentence is speaking  of what will happen if the author's warnings aren't heeded.
It means that psychotherapy must not embrace nihilism, because that is an incomplete picture of existence. If it does, it will harm the patient by confirming their feelings of worthlessness. The author believes that nihilism does not present a true picture of existence, but rather a caricature.

[Goodreads Frankl quote](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9284559-every-age-has-its-own-collective-neurosis-and-every-age)